# R Shiny app fails to start on server due to error about Rplots.pdf

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Shiny app runs fine on RStudio, but it doesn’t run on public server, throwing this error instead:

```
Error in (function (file = if (onefile) "Rplots.pdf" else "Rplot%03d.pdf",  : 
      cannot open file 'Rplots.pdf'
    Calls: runApp ... ..stacktraceon.. -> <Anonymous> -> par -> <Anonymous>
    Execution halted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears because there is code in your app that tries to generate a plot in a non-interactive R session (usually server.r or global.r).
To quote Yihui Xie:

> From my experience, this is often an indication that your have some
> code that generates plots in a non-interactive R session, and the
> default graphics device for a non-interactive R session is pdf(). R
> tried to capture the plot and writes Rplots.pdf, but failed probably
> due to the fact that you don't have write permission to the working
> directory.  Your server.R contains a call to palette(), which I
> believe will  trigger Rplots.pdf. You can try to move it inside
> renderPlot({}) and  see if the problem goes away.

In my case, it was a leftover call to `scales::show_col()` in my `global.r` file, from testing some color pallettes.